# How do I convert User::create method to json?

Tags: php, laravel

register with Laravel Ajax. Auth / RegisterController create function. But I can't use jquery because the `User::create` method does not return json.

```
$validation = $this->validator($data);

if($data['type'] == "customer" || $data['type'] == "company") {
    if ($validation->fails())  {
        return response()->json([$validation->errors()->toArray()], 400);
    }else {
            //how can i do json?
        return User::create([
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name'  => $data['last_name'],
            'email'      => $data['email'],
            'phone'      => $data['phone'],
            'password'   => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}else {
    return response()->json([
        0 => ['Üyelik sırasında bir hata oluştu. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz.']
    ], 404);
}
```

Comment: Your request in not a true ajax call, otherwise laravel would have converted your User instance into a json object automatically. check your call method. example `if($request->ajax()){ 'your code' }` to check if it is correctly sent

Comment: The create function also does not have $request variable parameter.

Comment: you can get the `$request` from the method of your controller `public method create(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {.....` or you can use the helper `request()->ajax()`

Comment: Please change your question. Otherwise, we have to flag this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can return json like this:

```
return response()->json(['user' => 
      User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name'  => $data['last_name'],
        'email'      => $data['email'],
        'phone'      => $data['phone'],
        'password'   => Hash::make($data['password']),
      ])
   ],200);
```

Since, create function returns the data you have created. I hope you understand.

According to docs,

> Once we have made the attributes mass assignable, we can use the create method to insert a new record in the database. The create method returns the saved model instance:

Comment: message: "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\yerikirala\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 35"

Comment: The problem you have mentioned is not belongs to above code. So, You have to look up your other codes

Answer (score 0):

store `user::create` in variable and return it as json

```
  $user = User::create([
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name'  => $data['last_name'],
            'email'      => $data['email'],
            'phone'      => $data['phone'],
            'password'   => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);


  return response([
    'user' => $user
  ],201)
```

Comment: message: "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\yerikirala\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 35"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
$validation = $this->validator($data);

    if($data['type'] == "customer" || $data['type'] == "company") {
        if ($validation->fails())  {
            return response()->json([$validation->errors()->toArray()], 400);
        }else {
            $user = User::create([
                'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
                'last_name'  => $data['last_name'],
                'email'      => $data['email'],
                'phone'      => $data['phone'],
                'password'   => Hash::make($data['password']),
            ]);
          return response()->json([
            0 => $user
        ], 200);
        }
    }else {
        return response()->json([
            0 => ['Üyelik sırasında bir hata oluştu. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz.']
        ], 404);
}
```

Comment: message: "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\yerikirala\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 35"

Comment: The issue is different. Check your user model. Did you modify it? Are you using laravel passport?

Comment: No, I don't use Laravel Passport.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with response code. But there is something wrong with your authentication system. Check that. Update us with that code here or on a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$userModel = User::create([
    'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
    'last_name'  => $data['last_name'],
    'email'      => $data['email'],
    'phone'      => $data['phone'],
    'password'   => Hash::make($data['password']),
]);
```

After you've created a User, you get a solid model which can be used further. If you want to return as JSON you can do it like this:

```
return response()->json(['user' => $userModel]);
```